# bash / sed : editing of the file

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I use sed to remove all lines starting from "HETATM" from the input file and cat to combine another file with the output recieved from SED

```
sed -i '/^HETATM/ d' file1.pdb
cat fil2.pdb file1.pdb > file3.pdb
```

is this way to do it in one line e.g. using only sed?

Comment: Something like this, if I understand you correctly?`(cat fil2.pdb; sed -i '/^HETATM/ d' file1.pdb) > file3.pdb`

Comment: yep this is a correct workflow. it may work directly like this in bash ??

Comment: `using only sed` : Are you open to other tools like `awk` as well?

Comment: I was actually wondering what the original reason was for `in one line`.

Comment: Why does it need to be in one line?

Comment: What you're doing with that sed is just excluding matching lines, so you could use `grep -v` for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to consider `awk` then it can be done in a single command:

```bash
awk 'FNR == NR {print; next} !/^HETATM/' file2.pdb file1.pdb > file3.pdb
```

Comment: Note that this does not have the side effect of modifying `file1.pdb`. It is not clear if that is a requirement.

Comment: yep it works, thank you! but actually this is the file1.pdb that should be modified.

Answer (score 1):

With `cat` + `grep` combination please try following code. Simple explanation would be, using `cat` command's capability to concatenate file's output when multiple files are passed to it and using `grep -v` to remove all words starting from `HETATM` in file1.pdb before sending is as an input to `cat` command and creating new file named `file3.pdb` from `cat` command's output.

```
cat file2.pdb <(grep -v '^HETATM' file1.pdb) > file3.pdb
```

Comment: @James Starlight, Good that you have accepted an answer, request you to kindly do check other answers as well so that contributors of other answers know how it went(just in case you want to check all answers) cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "remove all lines starting from 'HETATM'", but if you mean that any line that appears in the file after a line that starts with "`HETATM`" will not be outputted, then your `sed` expression won't do it - it will just remove all lines starting with the pattern while leaving all following lines that do not start with the pattern.

There are ways to get the effect I believe you wanted, possibly even with `sed` - but I don't know `sed` all that well. In `perl` I'd use the range operator with a guaranteed non-matching end expression (not sure what will be guaranteed for your input, I used "`XXX`" in this example):

```bash
perl -ne 'unless (/^HETATM/../XXX/) { print; }' file1.pdb
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mawk '(FNR == NR) < NF' FS='^HETATM' f1 f2
```